# Proving Linearly Independent Vectors over Finite Field

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, finite-fields

Suppose there are 4 vectors over $\mathbb{Z_{19}}$, namely  ${x_1} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1 \\ 
  {17} 
\end{array}} \right],{x_2} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1 \\ 
  7 
\end{array}} \right],{x_3} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1 \\ 
  1 
\end{array}} \right],{x_1} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1 \\ 
  9 
\end{array}} \right]$.
Are $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$  linearly independent vectors ?

Comment: They **must** be as they belong to $\;\left(\Bbb Z_{19}\right)^2\;$ , a two dimensional linear space over $\;\Bbb Z_{19}\;$ ...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you are saying. Care to explain ? @DonAntonio

Comment: If $\;F\;$ is *any* field, then the set $\;F^n\;$ of $\;n\,-$ vectors with entries in $\;F\;$ is a linear space of dimension $\;n\;$ over $\;F\;$ , with the usual termwise operations.